# Facebook graph api: upload multipart/form-data encoded image

Tags: image, facebook-graph-api, base64, multipartform-data

I am trying to post an image using the source parameter (Multipart/form-data) in the Graph API explorer. My source parameter looks like this:

```
{Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=xxxsrixxx

--xxxsrixxx
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=try2.gif
Content-Type: image/gif
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary,base64

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
```

--xxxsrixxx--}
This always seems to return

> {
>     "error": {
>       "message": "(#324) Requires upload file",
>       "type": "OAuthException",
>       "code": 324
>     }
>   }

Few questions:

1. Does facebook **source** parameter accept base64 encoded image data?
2. Has anyone tried using the source parameter in the graph api explorer and have a working sample?
3. should the source param value should be url-encoded?

Note: My access token has all the required permissions and if i am not wrong, my encoding seems to be wrong. The base64 encoded text above is a complete image and i could decode it and get the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. This is going to sound crazy. After a week of trying I was able to post an image successfully to the facebook wall. The fix was to send the raw binary data as it is (no base64 encoding - fb does not like it) and make sure your multipart/form-data is correct. For instance, if you boundary is defined as "**boundary=--xxxsrixxx**" your actual request should look like this "**----xxxsrixxx\r\nContent-Disposition......\r\n----xxxsrixxx**"

Comment: can you please send me the complete code.. Even I am struggling with the same

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me, it only uses native JavaScript features and a file input:

```js
const fileReader = new FileReader();
const file = document.getElementById('imageInput').files[0];

fileReader.onloadend = async () => {
    const photoData = new Blob([fileReader.result], {type: 'image/jpg'});
    const formData = new FormData();

    formData.append('access_token', pageAccessToken);
    formData.append('source', photoData);
    formData.append('message', 'some status message');

    let response = await fetch(`https://graph.facebook.com/${pageId}/photos`, {
        body: formData,
        method: 'post'
    });
    response = await response.json();
    console.log(response);
};
fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
```

More information: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-photo-upload-with-formdata/